# Unreachable function code detected in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm get 'unreachable code detected' error in this sample code below. Please help me to fix this Does it has anything to do with try and catch statements? the function UpdateCommentStatus is in the same cs file :

```
public string insertEmail(string pstrEmailFrom, string pstrEmailTo, string pstrEmailSubject, string pstrEmailBody, string pstrBRID, string pstrTicketID, int include_Attachment)
    {
        // Include Attachment is for keep track of only first email notification will contain attachment.
        // This is done to conserve bandwidth and processing. 
        string strSQL;
        string strEmailSubject = pstrEmailSubject.Replace("'", "''");
        string strEmailBody = pstrEmailBody.Replace("'", "''");
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO CRM_EMAIL(email_to,email_from,email_subject,email_body,created_date,";
        strSQL = strSQL + " br_id,notes,status,ticket_id, INCLUDE_ATTACHMENT,SEG_ID) VALUES ";
        strSQL = strSQL + "('" + pstrEmailFrom.Replace("'", "") + "','" + pstrEmailTo.Replace("'", "") + "','" + strEmailSubject + "', ";
        strSQL = strSQL + "'" + strEmailBody + "',NOW(), ";
        strSQL = strSQL + "'" + pstrBRID + "','','N', '" + pstrTicketID + "', " + include_Attachment + ",'" + mag.getSegID() + "')";
        mag.WriteToNormalLogFile("insertEmail()  strSQL:" + strSQL);
        try
        {
            objDBinterface.strConn = mag.ConnStr();
            objDBinterface.ExecSQL(strSQL);
            UpdateCommentStatus(pstrTicketID);
            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mag.WriteToLogFile("insertEmail : " + ex.ToString());
            return ex.ToString();
        }

        UpdateCommentStatus(pstrTicketID); <<-- HERE
    }
```

Comment: Won't you try use "using" statement?

Comment: I guess you don't need that line at all as you already called `UpdateCommentStatus` in `try`.

Comment: To better explain the error... (and feel free to add this to your answer Adil). If the try block is successful, you return out of the method, if it catches an error you return out of the method. So since you've returned already, that code never gets executed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to return in both `try` and `catch` block, The code after the catch block will never get a chance to get executed. You can move the return in the try block after the `UpdateCommentStatus` call or move `UpdateCommentStatus` before the return statement in the `try` block.

You can return an empty string in case of successful execution and an exception message in case of an error. You can consider the following options for returning an error.

- Make the return type bool and throw an execption.
- Return the bool and use out parameter to convey the error.